# Update a dataframe iteratively

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
    QID     URL     Questions   Answers     Section     QType   Theme   Topics  Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5     Answer6
1113    1096    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1hIkfKc2frAnxsQzGw_h4bIqasPwAPzzLFWqzPE3B_88/edit?usp=sharing   To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?   ['Very important consideration', 'Important consideration', 'Neutral', 'Not an important consideration', 'Do not consider']     When choosing an airline to fly with, which factors are most important to you? (Please list 3.)     Multiple Choice     Airline XYZ     ['extent', 'follow', 'factor', 'consider', 'choic', 'flight']   Very important consideration    Important consideration     Neutral     Not an important consideration  Do not consider     NaN     NaN
1116    1097    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1hIkfKc2frAnxsQzGw_h4bIqasPwAPzzLFWqzPE3B_88/edit?usp=sharing   How far in advance do you typically book your tickets?  ['0-2 months in advance', '2-4 months in advance', '4-6 months in advance', '6-8 months in advance', '8-10 months in advance', '10-12 months in advance', '12+ months in advance']  When choosing an airline to fly with, which factors are most important to you? (Please list 3.)     Multiple Choice     Airline XYZ     ['advanc', 'typic', 'book', 'ticket']   0-2 months in advance   2-4 months in advance   4-6 months in advance   6-8 months in advance   8-10 months in advance  10-12 months in advance     12+ months in advance
```

with rows of which I want to change a few lines that are actually QuestionGrid titles, with new lines that also represent the answers. I have a [other, Pickle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15boZG27t_DL8SEMn-ObyRMqKE3bCFR1I/view?usp=sharing), which contains the information to build the lines that will update the old ones. Each time an old line will be transformed into several new lines (I specify this because I do not know how to do it).

These lines are just the grid titles of questions like the following one:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Expected dataframe

I would like to insert them in the original dataframe, instead of the lines where they match in the 'Questions' column, as in the following dataframe:

```
QID    Questions     QType    Answer1    Answer2    Answer3    Answer4    Answer5                                                                        
1096      'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?'    Question Grid    'Very important consideration'    'Important consideration'    'Neutral'    'Not an important consideration'    'Do not consider'
1096_S01  'The airline/company you fly with'
1096_S02  'The departure airport'
1096_S03  'Duration of flight/route'
1096_S04  'Baggage policy'
1097      'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?'    Question Grid ...
1097_S01 ...
...
```

## What I tried

```
import pickle

qa = pd.read_pickle(r'Python/interns.p')
df = pd.read_csv("QuestionBank.csv")


def isGrid(dic, df):
    '''Check if a row is a row related to a Google Forms grid
    if it is a case update this row'''
    d_answers = dic['answers']
    try:
        answers = d_answers[2]
        if len(answers) > 1:
            # find the line in df and replace the line where it matches by the lines
            update_lines(dic, df)
        return df
    except TypeError:
        return df
        
def update_lines(dic, df):
    '''find the line in df and replace the line where it matches 
    with the question in dic by the new lines'''
    lines_to_replace = df.index[df['Questions'] == dic['question']].tolist() # might be several rows and maybe they aren't all to replace
    # I check there is at least a row to replace 
    if lines_to_replace:
        # I replace all rows where the question matches
        for line_to_replace in lines_to_replace:
            # replace this row and the following by the following dataframe
            questions = reduce(lambda a,b: a + b,[data['answers'][2][x][3] for x in range(len(data['answers'][2]))])
            ind_answers = dic["answers"][2][0][1]
            answers = []
            # I get all the potential answers
            for i in range(len(ind_answers)):
                answers.append(reduce(lambda a,b: a+b,[ind_answers[i] for x in range(len(questions))])) # duplicates as there are many lines with the same answers in a grid, maybe I should have used set
            answers = {f"Answer{i}": answers[i] for i in range(0, len(answers))} # dyanmically allocate to place them in the right columns
            dict_replacing = {'Questions': questions, **answers} # dictionary that will replace the forle create the new lines
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_replacing)
            df1.index = df1.index / 10 + line_to_replace
            df = df1.combine_first(df)
    return df
```

I did a [Colaboratory notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Th6DS0FdzKGn0yw6Vx53AXSFm_jWiFYR?usp=sharing) if needed.

## What I obtain

But the dataframe is the same size before and after we do this. In effect, I get:

```
QID    Questions     QType    Answer1    Answer2    Answer3    Answer4    Answer5                                                                        
1096      'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?'    Question Grid    'Very important consideration'    'Important consideration'    'Neutral'    'Not an important consideration'    'Do not consider'
1097      'To what extent are the following factors considerations in your choice of flight?'    Question Grid ...
```

Comment: update_lines only changes values in the DataFrame, but do not add rows. Why would you expect it to be a different size?

Comment: @WNG Thanks for your comment if I'm unclear: Because each time I find a line which `len(answers) > 1` I know it's a grid so I know I want to insert new lines that also represent the answers :)

Comment: Your links are restricted access. SO questions should be self-contained.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, damn, I sware I shared them so you could be able to access them ...